# "Invalid key code" when pressing some symbols with robot.keyPress

Tags: java, awtrobot

Does somebody know why I receive "Invalid key code" exception while trying to do a robot.keyPress of this symbol ';'?

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
```

.. neither this works:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

I am using an Spanish keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This do the job:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```